# What specific things need to check for URL using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, urllib2

I have few urls for that I want to check status so that I can keep track of its health. I figured out and coded for below using Python :

```
1)Status Code
2)Response Time
```

Please suggest if anything more need to be added to check.

URL's having both https and http. also Have  www.abc.com , www.abc.com/xyz/login.do  and similar type of pattern.

I am new to this so not much aware of what to check other than status code and response time.

Note: Timeout and few more error I have taken care of those.

There is no dependency. Mostly are application URLs hosted from the application server.

Comment: I would guess it depends on *why* you have decided that the URLs need to be checked in the first place. Are you monitoring them because of a dependency somewhere else. If so, what is the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to them, I recommend you to consider the case when the connection to the urls fails (maybe your program would raise an error). For example, lost of the Internet connection or out of DNS service can cause such a case.

If you're going to check some APIs, seeing Response Body would also be helpful.